# How do i get the original resolution of the image like it was when i open it normally outside python

Tags: python, opencv

I have changed the format of the images to png also..but of no use. Does cv2 / imshow decrease the resolution automatically?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv2.imread('image.png',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('2.png',0)
stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgR,imgL)

plt.imshow(disparity, 'gray')

plt.show()
```

My main aim is to generate the final image with the resolution as was the supplied images.

Comment: If you mean the dimensions of the two input images, then use numpy shape. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Comment: Provide all information in question also, not just in title. Probably your are confusing the way an image is shown with the actual resolution it has. No, Opencv does not change resolution.

Comment: @Eypros it doesn't help that there are multiple definitions of resolution. It could be the dimensions of the image, or it could be an EXIF tag giving you the DPI.

Comment: @Mark chances are the OP was not referring to the DPI but I am making a guess here of course.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `imshow` from matplotlib which **might** be the cause of different showing behaviour.
Instead try:

```
    cv2.imshow("Res", disparity)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If that is still not good, please edit the question and include the resulting image and the input image.